# Creating a chart with independently indexed series

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a data series that looks like this (bigger data set but that's accurate):

```
0           317.59
1.4         317.59
1.5         408.77
2.15        408.77
2.25        440.46
2.98        440.46
3.08        471.37
3.12        471.37
3.17        471.37
3.88        471.37
3.98        713.42
4.85        713.42
4.95        741.68
5.03        741.68
```

Where the left column are indexes and the right column is a series I want to graph with a line chart. I actually want to put several of these onto one chart, but I can only seem to specify one set of indexes for a series.

Is there a way to specify an independent set of horizontal axis values for each series with a line chart?

Or another chart that will work for doing that?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your requirement is as below, though this does not apply your sample data:

[image: WA53912 example]

The layout of the left four columns is required - in effect I have substituted:

10    100
30    110
60    150
80    180

for your sample data in the OP.

I selected the data area, Charts, Charts, Line  and checked both Use row 1 as headers and Use column A as labels. This ended up with the appearance of a scatter plot but in Advanced edit..., Customise, Features this, oddly, was fixed by checking Plot null values.

The colours, datapoints etc were customised for the image.